# Setting Spinner by name

Tags: android, spinner

can any one tell hw to set a spinner by name..
The scenario is like this,
Spinner contains three elements "one","two","three". After clicking the spinner im storing that  in shard pref say "two"
Now i wan to set to that spinner again to "two", if i open that activity again.
Array of the elements is in values/arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than storing the string value in your SharedPreferences, store the position within the array as an integer. Then you just call `Spinner.setSelection(int position)` with that value.

Comment: hmmm thanks you .. and can you tel me how to read this array  </array>
   
   This is there inside arrays.xml file under values
     <array name="Protocols">
      <item>100</item>
      <item>200</item>
      <item>300</item>
      <item>400</item>
      <item>500</item>
      <item>600</item>
      
     
   </array>

Comment: `getResources().getIntArray(R.array.Protocols)` should do the trick. That's assuming you're in onCreate, of course, you may have to get your Resources differently in other situations.

Comment: ya i can get ResId.. but i don knw how to parse through the resource

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `getIntArray()` returns an `int[]`. You get that, you have your array.